# Removing specific expression on Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have bookmarked a specific word in my document, it appears 4429 times. Now I just want to delete that word. The only option I can find is "delete bookmarked lines", but I don't want to get rid of the whole line, just the specific word.

Comment: You want to delete that word, or get rid of the bookmarks? Do you have other bookmarks or is it just these specific 4429 instances?

Comment: Does the word appear in the document in other places where it is not bookmarked?

Comment: You cannot delete specific text from bookmarked lines, as bookmarks manage complete lines. You need to use search and replace to delete text.

Answer (score 2):

In the Search menu, click the Replace command. In the dialog, enter your word in "Find what", clear the "Replace with", check the "Whole Word Only" and/or "Match Case" checkboxes if required. Then click "Replace All".